# Trying to bundle a package using browserify and it's creating an empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, browserify

I am trying to bundle a package using browserify so that I can use the require function on a browser.

I install browserify globally, and for my code used terminal command
`browserify stocksite.js > bundle.js`

It created an empty file called bundle.js. My stocksite.js is a file with the following code

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=3ZSN6PGMF9BH7XEX';

request.get({
   url: url,
   json: true,
   headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
 }, (err, res, data) => {
   if (err) {
     console.log('Error:', err);
   } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
     console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
   } else {
     // data is successfully parsed as a JSON object:
     console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Edited:
./node_modules/.bin/esbuild ./Desktop/stock-site-app/src/stocksite.js --bundle --outfile=Bundle.js

> node_modules/mysql/lib/ConnectionConfig.js:1:30: error: Could not resolve "url" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 1 │ var urlParse        = require('url').parse;
> ╵                               ~~~~~

> node_modules/express/lib/express.js:16:27: error: Could not resolve "events" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 16 │ var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
> ╵                            ~~~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:3:29: error: Could not resolve "events" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 3 │ var EventEmitter   = require('events').EventEmitter;
> ╵                              ~~~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/PoolCluster.js:5:28: error: Could not resolve "util" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 5 │ var Util          = require('util');
> ╵                             ~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:1:31: error: Could not resolve "crypto" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 1 │ var Crypto           = require('crypto');
> ╵                                ~~~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:4:29: error: Could not resolve "util" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 4 │ var Util           = require('util');
> ╵                              ~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/PoolCluster.js:6:28: error: Could not resolve "events" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 6 │ var EventEmitter  = require('events').EventEmitter;
> ╵                             ~~~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:2:31: error: Could not resolve "events" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 2 │ var Events           = require('events');
> ╵                                ~~~~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:3:31: error: Could not resolve "net" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 3 │ var Net              = require('net');
> ╵                                ~~~~~

> node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:4:31: error: Could not resolve "tls" (use "--platform=node" when building for node)
> 4 │ var tls              = require('tls');

In addition, I added to my package.json file the following in order to resolve the paths issue

"browser": {
"path": "path-browserify"
},

Comment: the code you're showing is not valid JS, and contains plain text as instructions for you to edit the file. Also, there is no `request` library in the browser, but there _is_ the universal `fetch` which works in the browser an in Node 18+ that you should be using instead, with the choice in bundler being interesting: browserify is kind of an old tool at this point, with something like esbuild being a much more obvious choice if you want to create a browser bundle.

Comment: The plain text is commented out

Comment: Look at the code you're showing in your post: it is not. So if it is in your own file, [edit] your post.

Comment: How would I write this code using the fetch() function?

Comment: This is what I came up with for replacing it with a fetch function      fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData))

Comment: yep. However, when you have `.then(...)`, also always remember to add a `.catch(...)` as well because you don't want uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Will do. Could you tell me where the data is now recorded as a Javascript object so I can iterate over it in JS?

Comment: it's that `jsonData`, which is not a "json data", that's your JS object. `response.json()` does not "give you JSON", it _parses_ the response in the assumption that it's JSON string data and yields the resulting native JS data.

Comment: An uncaught exception not a bad thing. Better than catching and ignoring

Comment: I have another question I edited my question to show. I tried esbuild in terminal and it came up with several errors as shown above